# Keep track and display arrival order of array elements after animation ends in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

So, I have created an array of 10 blocks(rectangles) that move horizontally towards a "finish" line (end of canvas width) with variable speeds. I'm looking for a way to keep track of the arrival order of each array element and display it on top of each rectangle as it stops moving. I've tried using a counter and the `fillText` method to do that, but it only works until other elements come to a full stop and then it replaces the order. For a better view of what happens, here is my code. If anyone has any suggestions on what to use in order to fulfill my goal, it is very much appreciated. Keep in mind that I only use plain JavaScript as in no jQuery or other frameworks as I am learning the basics. Thanks in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cars</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border:1px solid #3D0404;
        }
        h2 {
            margin-left:23%;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        var c;
        var ctx;
        var cars = [];
        var width = 100;
        var height = 100;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var i;
        var temp;
        var cw = 1000;
        var ch = 1000;


        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
                    return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                      function( callback ){
                      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                  };
        })();

        function init() {
            c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            ctx = c.getContext("2d");

            pushCar();

        }

        function CreateCar(x,y,width,height,speed){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.speed = speed;

        }

        function pushCar(){

            for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
                var speed = Math.random() * 10;
                var car = new CreateCar(x,y,width,height,speed);
                cars.push(car);
                y += 100;
            }

            drawAll();
        }

        function clear (){
            ctx.clearRect (0,0,cw,ch);
        }

        function draw(cars){

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
            ctx.fillRect(temp.x, temp.y, width, height);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
            ctx.outlineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeRect(temp.x, temp.y, width, height);  
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function drawAll(){
            clear();
            var z = 1;
            for (var i=0; i<cars.length; i++){

                temp = cars[i];
                draw(temp);
                if (temp.x+100 < c.width){
                temp.x += temp.speed;
                }else {                 
                    ctx.font = "20pt Verdana";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                    ctx.fillText(z, 950, temp.y+55);
                    z++;
                }
            }

            requestAnimFrame(drawAll, c);

        }


    </script>

</head>
<body onLoad = "init()">

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you just want to calculate the order in which they will arrive, once you know their start position, speed, and finish line position, you could easily calculate in how many steps it will reach end line

Comment: you need to move the z variable declaration and assignment out of the draw loop. Otherwise every time you draw a frame it will renumber the cars....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `z` variable outside the loop, and save the position of each car in an object. You also need to check if `position[i]` is already defined to avoid incrementing the current position more times than needed.

```
var z;
var position;
```

```
function drawAll() {
    clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        temp = cars[i];
        draw(temp);
        if (temp.x + 100 < c.width) {
            temp.x += temp.speed;
        } else {
            if (!position[i]) {
                position[i] = z;
                z++;
            }
            ctx.font = "20pt Verdana";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            ctx.fillText(position[i], 950, temp.y + 55);
        }
    }
    requestAnimFrame(drawAll, c);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acasaccia/u2vhaqyt/